# Osclass osc_user_phone () is not working

Tags: php, jquery, osclass

Recently i use this function to hide the last numbers of **osc_user_phone()** in Osclass 3.6.1

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#showPhone").click(function () {
            $("#showPhone").hide();
            $("#hidePhone").show();
        });

        $("#hidePhone").click(function () {
            $("#showPhone").show();
            $("#hidePhone").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<?php _e('user phone'); ?> :
<span>
    <a href="#"  id="hidePhone" style="display: none;">
        <?php echo osc_user_phone_mobile(); ?>
    </a>
</span>
<span>
    <a href="#"  id="showPhone">
        <?php echo substr(osc_user_phone_mobile(),0,-4).'XXXX'; ?>
    </a>
</span>
```

Up here everything is ok. If complete the Phone Cell field in User profile is ok, the phone number show in item page. 
If post a new ad, without account and complete the Cell Phone input, the phone number not showing in item page.

from **item-post.php**, problem is here (i hope)

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="phoneMobile"><?php _e('Cell phone', 'infinity'); ?></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php UserForm::mobile_text(osc_user()); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and from **user-profile.php**, the cell phone input:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="phoneMobile"><?php _e('Cell phone', 'infinity'); ?></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php UserForm::mobile_text(osc_user()); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

the same code that **item-post.php**

How do input field to work and when user posted new ad the phone number show in the item page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In osclass 3.7.1 (bender theme) I managed to put the registered user phone into item-post.php 
The code:

```
<?php if(osc_is_web_user_logged_in()) { ?>
 <?php if (!$edit) { ?>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="phoneLand"><?php _e('Phone', 'bender'); ?>*</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <?php UserForm::phone_land_text(osc_user()); ?>
<p style="font-size: 0.85em; color:red;">* empty => <u>it will miss from all the listings !</u></br>* filled => <u>it will show in all the listings !</u></p>
         </div>
    </div>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php if ($edit) { ?>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="phoneLand">The <?php _e('Phone', 'bender'); ?></label>
                <div class="controls">
<p style="font-size: 0.85em;"> can be edited <a href="<?php echo osc_user_profile_url(); ?>" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
         </div>
    </div>
 <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When submitting the page, Osclass checks whether it's a registered user or a non-registered user that is publishing an item.

1. If it founds a user id, infos are stored in the `oc_t_user` that has a `s_phone_land` and `s_phone_mobile`.
2. When a non-registered user is publishing an item, his infos are stored into the `oc_t_item` table in the database. Unfortunately, it only saves the `s_contact_name` and `s_contact_email`, no field is available is this table for the phone.

Then, your phone input field is submitted but just not taken into account by the controller. You can see the process in `controller/item.php` and `ItemActions.php`.

You might want to look at the `prepareData()` method in `ItemActions.php`, around lines 1100 to 1110:

```
if( $userId != null ) {
    $aItem['contactName']   = $data['s_name'];
    $aItem['contactEmail']  = $data['s_email'];
    Params::setParam('contactName', $data['s_name']);
    Params::setParam('contactEmail', $data['s_email']);
} else {
    $aItem['contactName']   = Params::getParam('contactName');
    $aItem['contactEmail']  = Params::getParam('contactEmail');
}
$aItem['userId']        = $userId;
```